# Autologin on Ubuntu 18.04 Cinnamon

Tags: 18.04, cinnamon, auto-login

I cannot find how to set autologin from 18.04 Cinnamon

Although there are several threads on this subject, none so far match what I have.

I do not have lightDM.
I do not have any button at top right of the User dialog.

I could have set it on installation but that might have inhibited me if anything went wrong later but before the new system was fully configured.

Answer (score 0):

https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/login-automatic.html.en

Edit the `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` file and make sure that the `[daemon]` section in the file specifies the following:

```
custom.conf

[daemon]
AutomaticLoginEnable=True
AutomaticLogin=username
```

Replace the username with the user that you want to be automatically logged in.